# Can I use the same pipe between 2 children processes in C?

Tags: c, linux

Ok.. so i'm trying to work with different processes.. I'm actually trying to create `|` as stated before and i've done so in a way where if my example is `ls | sort` then the stdout of ls goes into the stdin of sort. To do this I have just 1 pipe.. but i have to execute both commands at some point in the program and thus 2 `execvp()` are needed on my part. I've learned how to do this more or less.. so i'm going to make my question as plain as possible:

I have a child running and his job is to take `ls`. Before it executes `execvp()` i make it so that i `dup2(pipe1[1], 1)` so that the write end of the pipe replaces stdout. Once it executes `execvp()` he goes to the parent and the parent goes into an auxilary method whose job is to `fork()`. This creates another child and parent relationship.. and is passed a pointer to `pipe1` called `p1`. Using this pointer it `dup2(p1[0], 0)` to replace stdin with the read end of the pipe. Ideally this allows me to use the same pipe n amount of times as long as I keep doing this.

This child does the same thing the previous did and executes the second argument `sort`, and then returns to its parent who returns a flag integer pointing at the next `|` in the command line or to `NULL` and exiting if there is none. Can I do this? Is this possible? That is my question.

I would love to post some code but it's so damn long. I'm also just interested if in theory if what I said is possible, that is using the same pipe through several children, and if there is a clean way to do it, i'd like to be pointed toward it. I know there are better ways of doing this but I'd like to do it this way. This is not homework, just optional work for working with pipes in a non recursive environment. Thank you.

Comment: Take several hours to read e.g. [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) because we cannot explain all that in a few minutes. See also [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) and [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) wikipages.

Comment: I don't understand the "ideally this allows me to use the same pipe n amount of times as long as I keep doing this" ?  a | b | c uses 2 pipes (if you used only 1, if at all possible, then both a and b would "write" into it, and both b and c would "consume" from it, so  c AND b could get outputs from a mix of outputs a AND b ... why on earth? ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot copy a pipe, it is a file descriptor, it is a pipe with two ends. Use `tee` if you need more and named pipes.

You cannot copy a pipe means you can't access one end of it from two processes, the pipe cannot copy it's content.

Comment: If i point to a pipe though using a pointer.. can i manipulate that same pipe in other processes?

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure you _can_ copy the descriptor, and it will even work, it will only not work the way you expect (or rather, it will work _exactly_ the way _you_ would expect, but not the way the OP would). :-)

Comment: @Damon the descriptor will only work within the same process, it is certainly required that it need only work for one process (I can't see the OS having a global file table tbh... you could "fake" handles too easily). Also if you copy the file handle and one reads the input, when the other instance of the hander is used to read it wont get the data already read. If you have two identical file handles in the same process and one seeks, reading from the other reads from the new position.

Comment: @user2824512 DONT EVEN TRY THAT! The OS gives you a "token" (something you can give it and say "read" and it knows what you want to read by studying the token) it is only guaranteed to work for your process. It could be a simple number, the position in a list of files your process has +1 (because 0 means error IIRC), file 2 in one process could be different in another.

Comment: @AlecTeal: I think this may still "work". Only not quite as expected. For example the manpage to `fork` states: _"inherits copies of the parent's set of open file descriptors. Each file descriptor in the child refers to the same open file description as the corresponding file descriptor in the parent."_. That means no more and no less than that it's generally possible. Of course it is nonsensical, because once one process reads from the pipe, that content is "gone", and you have no hard guarantee (other than an implementation detail up to 16kB) that `read` is atomic.

Comment: @Damon it was written by people who know how an OS works (I know Linux specifically very well, especially on the FS front, but this is far from the filesystem parts, this is the end of the process I know) I think they think people will know this means seek-able files, and also that it wont be "the same file descriptor", it will just have the same value and access the same actual file. For example seeks to one wont affect the other.

Comment: @AlecTeal: OK, so you made me curious: http://ideone.com/PM95Dj  This doesn't produce any output on ideone, but on my Debian box, I very clearly get both children to read from the pipe and write a response to the console _more or less_ alternating. Most certainly not in-order, or atomic, and not really useful, but it "works" as much as one would expect. I'll leave it as homework for you to try if `dup` works the same (my guess is: yes).  :-)

Comment: @Damon I don't see why you couldn't access the same file handler like that, but the behavior is implementation defined. It also says runtime error on ideone (not sure what that is, never used) does it let you fork?

Comment: It most probably won't let you fork (which I guess is why it doesn't work there). That would be the ultra-denial-of-servic-exploit of the century if they'd let you fork. But feel free to compile it on your box quick, if you like (I'm used to write C++, not C99 so you probably have to save it as .cpp). What's implementation defined is whether the reads are atomic, and if you remove the `sleep` you see that indeed they aren't -- the children get half messages and toss them onto the console as intermingled garbage.